# can haproxy direct a request to a particular server

Tags: lua, haproxy

Can i get haproxy to redirect to a particular server based on the url.

eg: i have an incoming request like this

```
GET /servers/1234/stats
```

for that I want to do a GET on `http://centralhost/servers` - this would return an array of `{id,ip}`

find the server with `id 1234`...and return to caller the value of
`http://1234's ip/stats`

i am guessing Lua would help me out here, but i am not finding any good examples of lua with haproxy.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There's an idea that might help using acl.. if there are few numbers of servers you can add them statically in the configuration file.. and based on the coming id in the URL you can redirect the request to its corresponding server.

based on the answer in this thread: https://serverfault.com/questions/481801/haproxy-redirects-and-matching-based-off-uri

```
  frontend public
       bind *:80
       acl has_id path_beg -i /1234
       use_backend 1234_server_ip if has_id 

  backend 1234_server_ip
       server server_name 10.1.1.3:8080 check
```

Comment: How can we do this with HTTPS (443 port) but if our HAProxy is not managing the SSL certificates? is there some workaround or we can only read the IP and port in HAProxy without the SSL?